# How to use __len__ method rapper, Python 3.x

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I'm parsing an `XML` file, in which i use elements,currently my element name is  `__word__`
In the elements I have an attribute called `__attrs__`,
When I debug I can see this `__attrs__` has a method wrapper called `__len__`
I would like to use it in order to know the length of `_attrs` but i guess i dont know how.
i tried :

```
word._attrs.__len__

word._attrs.len()

len(word._attrs)
```

I guess you know it didn't work :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`len(word._attrs)` is the way to go if you want the length of whatever is in `_attrs`.

`word._attrs.__len__()` would work too but you are not supposed to call those magic methods directly.